# Remove image from span on screen resize | jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add and remove images from span dependable on screen size.

I have 1 event handler to check the screen size and fire one of the functions if condition is true.

Here is my event handler:

```
    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        var innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
        if (innerWidth < 1000) {
            ApplyIconsToMobileNav();
            console.log("apply icons hit");
        } else if (innerWidth > 1000) {
            RemoveIconsDesktopNav();
            console.log("removed icons hit");
        }
    });
```

Here is my apply icons function:

```
        function ApplyIconsToMobileNav() {
            var Categories = jQuery(".nav-menu > .nav-mobile > .nav-item > a").find("span:first-of-type");
                jQuery(Categories).each(function() {
                    var Category = jQuery(this).text();
                    if(Category == "E-Liquid") {
                        jQuery(this).html("<img src='/media/wysiwyg/purple_icons/e-liquid(32x32).png' />" + Category);
                    } else if (Category == "E-Cigarette Kits") {
                        jQuery(this).html("<img src='/media/wysiwyg/purple_icons/e-cigarette(32x32).png' />" + Category);
                    } 
                });
        };
```

And here is my remove icons function:

```
       function RemoveIconsDesktopNav() {
            var CategoriesImg = jQuery(".nav-menu > .nav-mobile > .nav-item > a").find("span:first-of-type");
                jQuery(CategoriesImg).each(function() {
                    jQuery("img", this).hide();
                });
        };
```

I have a lot more images in the navigation but pasted only relevant code. My event listener is working fine, so is the `ApplyIconsToMobileNav()` function, however, I can't get the `RemoveIconsDesktopNav()` to work. I know, that I can do exactly the same thing I did in the `ApplyIconsToMobileNav()` but add style of `display: none` to the image but I want to select all images from the selected span and hide/remove them.

Comment: you can do this with media queries and just add/remove a display:none; under/over 1000px. Am I wrong?

Comment: Add a class to the images and then use media queries to hide? That could be a solution... I am still interested how to select those added images using jQuery and hide them.

Comment: Using mediaqueries to hide/show stuff *is* the solution.

Comment: Hymmm... that might be true, I wont need the event listener and only one function to add the images with one CSS media query that controls the display. I think, I overthink-ed it :D

Comment: We probably need the HTML to figure out why RemoveIconsDesktopNav() does not work.

Comment: Can you show a working snippet so we can reproduce the issue? Media queries are nice for this but OP is interested in making this implementation work

Comment: I'll try to make a working snippet now, please bare with me.

Comment: Try using `$(this).find('img').hide();` instead of `jQuery("img", this).hide();`. You can also use `.toggle();` instead of `.hide();` if you wish to alternate between show/hide.

Comment: Boom, while trying to get the fiddle working. The `$(this).find('img').hide();` mentioned by @Martin worked!

Comment: Like to the fiddle if anyone is interested: https://jsfiddle.net/Lgo5aumh/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with this syntax: `jQuery("img", this).hide();`

However, you could try the following: `$(this).find('img').hide();`

Alternatively, you can also use `.toggle();` instead of `.hide();` if you wish to alternate between show/hide.

Comment: I got the syntax from here which seems to be correct (7 upvotes?): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023453/jquery-img-select .Anyway, thaks for you time and help!

Comment: Glad it helped, and yeah, it could be correct syntax, I just personally haven't encountered it before.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of jQuery use CSS Media Queries. eg-

**This CSS will work only when screen is than 767px that is a normal mobile screen**

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
    .class_name img{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: The comments of this thread already covered media queries, but we'd like to honor OP's request by following his methods and make them work.